# JMeter variable Encoding is not correct

Tags: encoding, utf-8, jmeter, response, extract

I'm using Jmeter 5.3 on Windows 10. I'm facing with the following problem:
I set the HTTP request to content encoding: UTF-8. In the response I saw it as I wanted.

```
"name": "Győr, autóbusz-állomás",
```

I tried to extract the response with JSON Extractor, but my assertion is failed and in the debug sampler the extracted name look like:

```
origin.name=Gy�r, aut�busz-�llom�s
```

How could I extract the variable in UTF-8 to use it in my assertion?

Thank you in advice,

Comment: It looks as if something is trying to treat your input as ANSI or Latin-1 rather than a UTF-8 btye stream. Probably whaterver reads it first.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. It was resolved with setting in HTTP Request "UTF-8" value on field "Content encoding".

Without it in my request was "???" symbols.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just made it for Norwegian.

1. Go to jmeter.properties file which is in the bin folder
2. Find --> 'sampleresult.default.encoding=UTF-8'
3. Remove the # before this text. Should look like this:
   # The encoding to be used if none is provided (default ISO-8859-1)
   sampleresult.default.encoding=UTF-8
4. Save and close the file
5. Restart jmeter & enjoy

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue:

[image]

Double check `file.encoding` System property value using the Debug Sampler, you should have `UTF-8`

[image]

If you don't - try launching JMeter as:

```
jmeter -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

if it helps - add `file.encoding=UTF-8` line to *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation, JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.

More information:

- [Guide to Character Encoding](https://www.baeldung.com/java-char-encoding)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately it does not help. I tried to bypass this problem but i have another one: 
I am using 'Property Reader' to read my variables. I heard that the 'Property Reader' plugin can not read UTF8 characters. Is it true?
My request looks like: "requestString": "GyÃ¶r, autÃ³busz-Ã¡llomÃ¡s", when i

Answer (score 0):

Try to resolve with:

- Go to ***jmeter.properties*** file
- Add property: ***sampleresult.default.encoding=UTF-8***
- Restart jmeter & enjoy

Good luck!